# K means clustering on long format data

Tags: clustering, k-means

I have a dataset of customers and some of their characteristics, including the total worth of goods purchased. Essentially, I have transaction line items. My data looks something like this:

```
   customer_ID     char1    char2     char3     total_purchase
       1             4        3         6           450
       1             3        5         2           450
       1             6        10        4           450
       2             5        3         11          500
       2             34       4         23          500
       3             2        1         4           330
       3             4        5         12          330
```

I want to run a cluster analysis, and then look at what characteristics drive purchase (using regressions or some other appropriate technique).

I know this will not affect my feature selection (I plan to use the Boruta package in R for mixed type data). However, I imagine this will be problematic for clustering since I would like lists of customers as the end of this exercise, and the characteristics that drive sales within each group. I imagine I may end up with one customer in multiple groups, since I will be using total_purchase as my outcome variable. I would appreciate if you could explain how the structure of my data will affect my analysis plan.

Comment: So... your plan is to use cluster analysis and regression and boruta ... and you may or may not have an outcome variable. Can you explain to us what is your actual research question, what are you trying to answer? And forget about what you have tried so far or what your plan is.

Comment: I want to understand what drives purchases among different clusters of customers. My outcome variable is total_purchase